# I create a like button ,but after refresh the page ,the like count becomes 0

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I create a like button, when click it ,first check whether the user is logged in.Only logged in , the user can click the like button and the like counts add 1.But everytime refresh page,the counts become 0 again.Why this would be happen?
html:

```
<div class="post-footer">
 <div class="flag">
 <span class="flag-wrapper">
 <a class="flag-action" href="#">
 <i class="fa fa-heart-o" ></i>
 <span class="count">0</span>
 <span class="flag-text" >Like this news post</span>
 </a>
 </span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click", ".flag" ,function(){
    //
    var count = $(".count").text();
    //
    var id= $(".ds-subtitle").attr("rel");
    // alert(id);
    alert(count);
     $.ajax({
        url:"functions/php/like.php",
        type:"POST",
        // cache:false,
        data:{count:count,id:id},
        success:function(data){
            // alert(data);
            // console.log(data);
            if (data == "0") {
                alert("do not log in");
                $("#popup-box1").show();
            } 
            if (data == "1"){
                alert("already log in");
                $("#popup-box1").hide();
                // alert();
                 count++;
                $("span .count").text(count);   
            }
        }          
    });
});
});
```

php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["id"])) {

    echo "0";


}else{
    echo "1";//
    //
    $id= $_POST["id"];
    // 
    $userid = $_SESSION["id"];
    //   
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "maroon5");

    //
    $sql = " INSERT INTO fav (news_id,  user_id) 
             VALUES ('$id', '$userid') ";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


}
?>
```

Comment: Which part of your code retrieves the like count from the database and shows it to the user?

Comment: adding 1 to an mysql row requires `UPDATE`. You're most likely overwriting your value.

Answer (score 0):

> But everytime refresh page,the counts become 0 again

Because your function will be only called `onclick`

```
$(document).on("click", ".flag" ,function(){
```

You probably need to call same method or refresh method `onload`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve this.I put this

```
    <?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "maroon5");

    $sql1 = " SELECT * FROM fav WHERE news_id=1 ";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $nums = mysqli_num_rows($res1);

    ?>
    <div class="post-footer">
     <div class="flag">
     <span class="flag-wrapper">
     <a class="flag-action" href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-heart-o" ></i>
         <?php
            echo "<span class='count'>". $nums  ."</span>";
          ?>
           <!-- <span class="count">0</span> -->
            <span class="flag-text" >Like this news post</span>
     </a>
     </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </article>
    </div>
    </div>
```